# Vernacular V. Definition

Tags: meaning

I think the English language is far beyond us, but, I'm curious:

Is it better to know the definition to a word, or is it better to know how to use a word?

Comment: Who's "us"?....

Comment: @deadrat I have no idea what I was talking about! Weird phrasing... :(

Answer (score 1):

I see you are into words. I am too, but not as enthusiastically as I use to be; however, I'll go to my grave learning new words and revisiting the old ones again and again.

It's not a matter of comparison. Whether you know it or not, or believe it or not, we use words whether we know the actual definition(s) or not. Man, there're books written on this topic.

I use to speak some Italian when I was younger, and didn't have a clue except by sight and sound, inference, implication, ascertainment, and so forth as to what the heck I was saying.

Forget that and chew on this:

The two *biggies* I do are:

Plug in the actual definition per part of speech to help me understand a word or how to use it, and my own rule: (this, from many years of studying English grammar and composition)

"Every word in a sentence not only functions as a part of speech but also serves a purpose in the sentence."--Arch Denton.

Think about it. Let's use a very simple sentence.

*I like coffee.*

Now, this is easily diagrammed...

I | like | coffee

Subject | verb | direct object

But, check this out...

I = **function**: First Person, pronoun, singular; **purpose**: subject of the sentence

like = **function**: verb (transitive); **purpose**: to be the action verb acting upon the subject of the sentence to answer "Who?" or "What?" What do I like? Coffee.

coffee = **function**: common noun; **purpose**: direct object of the verb, answering "What?"

This may sound trivial or even stupid or crazy to you but it can be used with any word, even if the word is implied or understood:

Let's use an imperative sentence:

Bring me a cup of coffee.

The understood (you) *functions* as a Second Person, pronoun, singular, and it's *purpose* is subject of the sentence.

Between plugging in definitions and examining the function and purpose of a word, I manage to keep my peace of mind to some extent when encountering literal *demons* I can barely grasp per definition AND use. I find it especially helpful when diagramming sentences too.